# How can I use multiprocessing to speed up bs4 scraping and image downloading

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, multiprocessing, screen-scraping

So I have this piece of code:

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
import os
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\fani\Desktop\History.csv')

folder_name = "downloadedpics"
os.mkdir(folder_name)

z=1

for j in df['url']:

    # DOWNLOAD ALL IMAGES FROM THAT URL
    def download_images(images, folder_name):
        # initial count is zero
        count = 0

        # print total images found in URL
        print(f"Total {len(images)} Image Found!")

        # checking if images is not zero
        if len(images) != 0:
            for i, image in enumerate(images):
                # From image tag ,Fetch image Source URL

                # 1.data-srcset
                # 2.data-src
                # 3.data-fallback-src
                # 4.src

                # Here we will use exception handling

                # first we will search for "data-srcset" in img tag
                try:
                    # In image tag ,searching for "data-srcset"
                    image_link = image["data-srcset"]

                # then we will search for "data-src" in img
                # tag and so on..
                except:
                    try:
                        # In image tag ,searching for "data-src"
                        image_link = image["data-src"]
                    except:
                        try:
                            # In image tag ,searching for "data-fallback-src"
                            image_link = image["data-fallback-src"]
                        except:
                            try:
                                # In image tag ,searching for "src"
                                image_link = image["src"]

                            # if no Source URL found
                            except:
                                pass

                # After getting Image Source URL
                # We will try to get the content of image
                try:
                    r = requests.get(image_link).content
                    with open(f"{folder_name}/{z}images{i + 1}.jpg", "wb+") as f:
                        f.write(r)

                    # counting number of image downloaded
                    count += 1
                except:
                    pass

            # There might be possible, that all
            # images not download
            # if all images download
            if count == len(images):
                print("All Images Downloaded!")

            # if all images not download
            else:
                print(f"Total {count} Images Downloaded Out of {len(images)}")


    # MAIN FUNCTION START
    def main(url):
        # content of URL
        r = requests.get(url)

        # Parse HTML Code
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

        # find all images in URL
        images = soup.findAll('img', class_='pannable-image')

        # Call folder create function
        download_images(images, folder_name)


    # take url
    url = j

    # CALL MAIN FUNCTION
    main(url)
    print(z)
    z = z + 1
```

it scrapes a bunch of urls (listed in history.csv) and downloads some images from them.
the only problem is it's really slow for such a simple task.
what is the correct way to implement multiprocessing to speed it up?
I'm a newbie and I don't know how multiprocessing works

Edit:
Here is the csv file:
[mega link](https://mega.nz/file/m7JTCagD#QYpVJUxDYekhXEK2wvLcD7ZsJobuJRGqlPgIMjKJ9Fo)

The code is supposed to download about 12000 images which amounts to about 1GB of data from 1648 webpages (the gallery portion of the pages on this e-commerce site)

Comment: The bit to optimize for with requests would be using async as I/O bound rather than multiprocessing.

Comment: can you show me how that's done? how much time could I potentially save using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already are using the `requests` package, the obvious way to proceed is to use `multithreading` rather than `asyncio`, which would require you to abandon `requests` and learn `aiohttp`.

I have done quite a bit of restructuring of the code and as I have been unable to test it not having access to your CSV file, I strongly suggest you review what I have done and try to understand it as best possible by reading the Python documentation for the various classes and methods that are new to you. What I did not understand is why when you retrieve a an image file you attempt to decode it. I suppose you expect that to generate an error but it just seems like a waste of time.

I have arbitrarily set the multithreading pool size to 100 (multithreading can easily handle a pool size several times larger, although asyncio can handle thousands of concurrent tasks). Set `N_THREADS` to the number of URLs multiplied by the average number of images per URL you need to be downloading, but not more than 500.

```py
from bs4 import *
import requests
import os
import pandas
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial
from threading import Lock

    
class FileIndex:
    """
    Increment and return the next index to use for creating a file
    that is threadsafe.
    """
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._file_index = 0

    @property
    def next_file_index(self):
        with self._lock:
            self._file_index += 1
            return self._file_index


# DOWNLOAD AN IMAGE FROM THAT URL
def download_image(image, session, file_index, folder_number, folder_name):
    # From image tag ,Fetch image Source URL

    # 1.data-srcset
    # 2.data-src
    # 3.data-fallback-src
    # 4.src

    # Here we will use exception handling

    # first we will search for "data-srcset" in img tag
    try:
        # In image tag ,searching for "data-srcset"
        image_link = image["data-srcset"]

    # then we will search for "data-src" in img
    # tag and so on..
    except:
        try:
            # In image tag ,searching for "data-src"
            image_link = image["data-src"]
        except:
            try:
                # In image tag ,searching for "data-fallback-src"
                image_link = image["data-fallback-src"]
            except:
                try:
                    # In image tag ,searching for "src"
                    image_link = image["src"]

                # if no Source URL found
                except:
                    return 0 # no image loaded

    # After getting Image Source URL
    # We will try to get the content of image
    try:
        r = session.get(image_link).content
        # Why are you trying to decode an image?
        try:
            # possibility of decode
            r = str(r, 'utf-8')
            return 0 # no error return 0 ?????

        except UnicodeDecodeError:

            # After checking above condition, Image Download start
            with open(f"{folder_name}/{folder_number}images{file_index.next_file_index}.jpg", "wb+") as f:
                f.write(r)

            # counting number of image downloaded
            return 1 # 1 downloaded
    except:
        return 0 # 0 downloaded

# download_url FUNCTION START
def download_url(folder_number, url, session, folder_name, thread_pool):
    # content of URL
    r = session.get(url)

    # Parse HTML Code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    # find all images in URL
    images = soup.findAll('img', class_='pannable-image')

    # Call folder create function
    worker = partial(download_image,
                     session=session,
                     file_index=FileIndex(),
                     folder_number=folder_number,
                     folder_name=folder_name)
    counts = thread_pool.map(worker, images)
    total_counts = sum(counts)
    if total_counts == len(images):
        print(f"All Images Downloaded for URL {url}!")
    else:
        print(f"Total {total_counts} Images Downloaded Out of {len(images)} for URL {url}")

# The real main function:
def main():
    df = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\fani\Desktop\History.csv')
    folder_name = "downloadedpics"
    os.mkdir(folder_name)
    
    N_THREADS_URLS = 50 # or some suitable size for retrieving URLS
    N_THREADS_IMAGES = 500 # or some suitable size for retrieving images

    # use a session for efficiency:
    with requests.Session() as session, \
    ThreadPool(N_THREADS_URLS) as thread_pool_urls, \
    ThreadPool(N_THREADS_IMAGES) as thread_pool_images:
        worker = partial(download_url,
                         session=session,
                         folder_name=folder_name,
                         thread_pool=thread_pool_images)
        results = thread_pool_urls.starmap(worker, enumerate(df))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, It works and It is pretty fast. But for some reason it doesn't save all the pictures and the number of pictures saved varies run by run for the same data and pages. It also apparently stops processing after a certain number of urls if n_threads is smaller than the number of urls (I think). I also added the link to my csv in OP. I guess this is not for me and I need to study more about multithreading and/or aiohttp since I don't fully understand them. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I clicked on the link and it says "The file you requested has been deleted".

Comment: And yes, `N_THREADS` must be greater than the number of URLS you have. I have updated the answer instead two use *two* separate thread pools, one for retrieving URLs and another for retrieving images. Each one could theoretically be as small as 1. But set them to the size that approximates the number of URLs and images you have respectively but again keeping an upper limit of approximately 500.

Comment: Did you try the updated code? And what about the missing CSV file?

Comment: It does work, but like I said I have about 1700 urls and about 12000 pics so 500 isn't going to do it for me. And when I set N_THREADS_URLS = 1700 and N_THREADS_IMAGES = 12000 it chokes the weak system I have at work mainly on RAM (but it seems to be working, I need to test more to be sure). I updated the csv file link as well

Comment: update: with  N_THREADS_URLS = 1700 and N_THREADS_IMAGES = 12000 it just stops processing after a while and sits there doing nothing without any exit code or anythinh

Comment: You did not listen! And did you make an effort to read the documentation to understand how thread pools work? **I told you not to exceed 500 threads.** Even setting a value of 1 will *eventually* complete all the work; it would be the equivalent of just doing serial processing like you have been doing. The size of the pool just determines how many retrievals can be done concurrently. So when a thread in the pool finishes doing a retrieval it then will do *another* retrieval if there is more work to be done.

Comment: I just wanted to experiment with higher numbers and fortunately nothing problematic occurred but I'm sorry anyways. I am actually reading documentation on Python's site. On a side note, this project's deadline has passed and I will gain nothing from it and am just trying to learn. I set the params to 500 both and it works. THANKS